# How to hover <td> that contain specific data

Tags: html, jquery, css, hover

I need to display **red background color** in `<td>` that I hovered. For example, if I hovered 'Apple', then 'Apple' in all `<td>` shall be hovered same color as well. Currently can only hover one `<td>Apple</td>`.

```css
table {
margin: 2rem;
}

th, td {
border: 1px solid #333;
}

td:hover{
background-color:red
}

html {
font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Table 1</h3>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Header 1.1</th>
<th>Header 1.2</th>
<th>Header 1.3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apple</td>
<td>Orange</td>
<td>Lemon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Orange</td>
<td>Lemon</td>
<td>Apple</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nueza99/pen/abwKPLK?editors=1000)

Comment: Please show us your code so far and could you explain a bit more clearly what is required? If the user hovers over a td which consists of just the word Apple then all other tds which have the word somewhere in their content get highlighted too, or is it something else?

Comment: Hi, I have put my code in Codepen, and If User hover Apple, all Apple shall be highlighted, if user hover Lemon, all Lemon highlighted

Comment: @Muneeb K I have posted my answer consider it a go

Comment: OP you should accept [A Haworth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278832/13001728) as it gives a thorough explanation. Almost all other answers are code-only answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the help of `jQuery`. Try running the following snippet.

```js
$('.apple').hover(
  function(){
        $('.apple').css({"background":"red"});
  },function(){
        $('.apple').css({"background":"white"});
  })
  
$('.orange').hover(
  function(){
        $('.orange').css({"background":"orange"});
  }
  ,function(){
        $('.orange').css({"background":"white"});
  }
)

$('.lemon').hover(
  function(){
        $('.lemon').css({"background":"yellow"});
  }, function(){
        $('.lemon').css({"background":"white"});
})
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 24px;
}

table {
  margin: 2rem;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

td span {
  display: block;
}

td:hover span.apple {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Table 1</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1.1</th>
    <th>Header 1.2</th>
    <th>Header 1.3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="apple">Apple</span></td>
    <td><span class="orange">Orange</span></td>
    <td><span class="lemon">Lemon</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="orange">Orange</span></td>
    <td><span class="lemon">Lemon</span></td>
    <td><span class="apple">Apple</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain what you did in the code? This is literally a code-only answer which, I'm afraid, is frowned upon here

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done with just HTML and CSS as CSS is not aware of content.

Using Javascript you can set CSS variables that in turn will set the background of a cell.

This snippet goes through each td element and sets the style background: var(--name of fruit) so for example all apple cells have the style="background: var(--apple);" added to them. Then when a td is hovered the JS sets the --apple to red and when the mouse moves out it sets it to transparent.

That way all those tds with background: var(--apple) get highlighted.

There is no need to iterate through all the cells in the table each time a hover takes place, you can do it by setting everything up once at the start.

```js
function setHighlight(e) {
  table.style.setProperty('--' + e.target.textContent, 'red');
}

function removeHighlight(e) {
  table.style.setProperty('--' + e.target.textContent, 'transparent');
}
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
tds.forEach(td => {
  td.addEventListener('mouseover', setHighlight);
  td.style.backgroundColor = 'var(--' + td.textContent + ')';
});
tds.forEach(td => {
  td.addEventListener('mouseout', removeHighlight);
});
```

```html
<h3>Table 1</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1.1</th>
    <th>Header 1.2</th>
    <th>Header 1.3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in every td and use JQuery.
See the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td.apple").hover(function(){
    $(".apple").css("background-color", "red");
    }, function(){
    $(".apple").css("background-color", "white");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td class="apple">Apple</td>
    <td class="apple">Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td class="apple">Apple</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td class="apple">Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want to add extra IDs and add jquery as dependency to Your code, You can use vanilla JS

```
// Get all TDs
const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("td"));

tds.map(td => {
  
  // bind mouseenter to TDs to paint BG
  td.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
    const text = event.target.textContent;
    
    // paint TDs with same text
    tds.map(td => {
      if(td.textContent === text) {
        td.style.background = 'red';
      }
    });

  });
  
  // bind mouseleave to TDs to remove BG
  td.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
   
    tds.map(td => {
      td.style.background = 'transparent';
    });
  })
});
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/ipasha/pen/eYRKxpP

Answer (score -1):

```css
table {
  margin: 2rem;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.apple:hover{
  background-color:red
}

html {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Table 1</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1.1</th>
    <th>Header 1.2</th>
    <th>Header 1.3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="apple">Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Lemon</td>
    <td class="apple">Apple</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you've got it wrong. He wants to color all instances of apple when apple is hovered and not from class but text inside it

Comment: Also, this is a code-only answer. You should explain how to get round the problem

Answer (score -1):

This is one way you can try:

```css
html {
  font-size: 24px;
}

table {
  margin: 2rem;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

td span {
  display: block;
}

td:hover span.apple {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<h3>Table 1</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1.1</th>
    <th>Header 1.2</th>
    <th>Header 1.3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="apple">Apple</span></td>
    <td><span>Orange</span></td>
    <td><span>Lemon</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Orange</span></td>
    <td><span>Lemon</span></td>
    <td><span class="apple">Apple</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this only highlights the hovered element, not all apples.